# R data frame - logical test with na's

Tags: r, dataframe, logical-operators

I have a data frame (SCV) with a field (DELETE_CUSTOMER).  I want to delete rows in the data frame where DELETE_CUSTOMER != "Y".  At the moment, this field is all `NA` - but this is a data frame that grows over time so it could have Y's in the future.

At the moment I am trying the following:

```
DELETIONS <- which(is.na(SCV_DELTA_R$DELETE_CUSTOMER) !=T &
                         SCV_DELTA_R$DELETE_CUSTOMER == "Y")
SCV_DELTA_R <- SCV_DELTA_R[-DELETIONS, ]
```

This gives me the same number of rows, but all values are `NA` on all fields in the table.

The DELETIONS list contains nothing and is given as:

```
integer(0)
```

So rather than deleting nothing, it removes all data.

Comment: Try `!is.na(SCV_DELTA_R$DELETE_CUSTOMER)` instead of `is.na(SCV_DELTA_R$DELETE_CUSTOMER)!=T`. Does that work?

Comment: Apparently, `data[-0,]` removes all the entries from the data frame data (since it selects nothing)

Answer (score 0):

The expression

```
which(is.na(SCV_DELTA_R$DELETE_CUSTOMER)!=T & SCV_DELTA_R$DELETE_CUSTOMER=="Y")
```

returns an empty result because you said that you don't have any "Y" in your data.frame: the expression selects rows where the value is equal to "Y" (that implies also that is not "NA", so it would not be useful to include also the first part of your expression).

Since you don't have any "Y", the expression returns empty, therefore DELETIONS is empty and the call `SCV_DELTA_R[-DELETIONS,]` completely clears your table.

If you want to delete all rows with value "Y" **OR** NA I suggest:

```
DELETIONS=which(is.na(SCV_DELTA_R$DELETE_CUSTOMER) | SCV_DELTA_R$DELETE_CUSTOMER=="Y")
```

If you want to delete all rows only with value "Y" I suggest:

```
DELETIONS=which(SCV_DELTA_R$DELETE_CUSTOMER=="Y")
```

If you want to delete all rows only with NA I suggest:

```
DELETIONS=which(is.na(SCV_DELTA_R$DELETE_CUSTOMER))
```

If you want to delete all rows only with value different than "Y" I suggest (this will clear your table since you said you don't have any "Y"):

```
DELETIONS=which(SCV_DELTA_R$DELETE_CUSTOMER!="Y")
```

I hope this may help you.

Answer (score 0):

You could flip the logic around to select what you want to keep, which would be any entry that isn't `"Y"`

```
SELECTIONS <- !SCV_DELTA_R$DELETE_CUSTOMER %in% "Y"

SCV_DELTA_R <- SCV_DELTA_R[SELECTIONS, ]
```

Values that are `NA` should thus be included in `SELECTED`